# SetSecurityInfo error = 6

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am new to c++ programming on the windows kernel. For the last few hours been trying to figure out how this works. So basically this is my error             SetSecurityInfo(hNewDesktop) failed error = 6. It passes the first loop but then I am unable to SetSecurityInfo for the new desktop.

```
    HDESK dNew;
    BOOL closedesk;
    HANDLE hApp;
    HDESK hThreadDT = GetThreadDesktop(GetCurrentThreadId());
    //Make a new desktop
    dNew = CreateDesktop(_T("test"), 0, 0, 0, DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP|
                                              DESKTOP_WRITEOBJECTS|
                                              DESKTOP_READOBJECTS|
                                              DESKTOP_ENUMERATE|
                                              DESKTOP_CREATEWINDOW|
                                              DESKTOP_CREATEMENU, NULL);

    if(!dNew)
    {
        _tprintf(_T("Failed to create new desktop !!\n\n"));
        return 0;
    }

PACL pSacl;
PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSecurityDescriptor;
DWORD dwResult;

dwResult = GetSecurityInfo(hThreadDT, SE_WINDOW_OBJECT, LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, NULL, NULL, NULL, &pSacl, &pSecurityDescriptor);

if (dwResult == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    if (pSacl != NULL) {
        dwResult = SetSecurityInfo(_T("test"), SE_WINDOW_OBJECT, LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, NULL, NULL, NULL, pSacl);

        if (dwResult != ERROR_SUCCESS)
            _tprintf(_T("SetSecurityInfo(hNewDesktop) failed, error = %d"), dwResult);
    }

    LocalFree(pSecurityDescriptor);
} else {
    _tprintf(_T("GetSecurityInfo(hDefaultDesktop) failed, error = %d"), dwResult);
}
```

Comment: *fixed _T("test") to dNew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error code 6 is `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`. That makes sense because you passed `_T("test")` which is a null terminated string and not a desktop handle. Pass `dNew` instead.

Comment: Now I get error = 5 it means access is denied. I don't understand how do I get it working?

Comment: Well, that's a new and different problem. That's `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. You don't need me to look them up for you though. They are documented: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: What can I do about ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED?

Comment: I don't know. That's a different question. I don't know what you are trying to achieve, what the context is, and so on. I just answered the question you asked which related to code that led to `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`.

Comment: Yea, I understand. good job! Should I open another thread? Or can you add any suggestions? I really appreciate you help

Comment: You could ask another question. You'd do well to state you overall goal and ask how to achieve it.

Comment: I want to run IE in a new desktop but first I want to copy the lpsecuritydescriptor from the current desktop.

Comment: I reverted your question edit. It made my answer look stupid. Don't ask a new question by changing this one. If you have a different question, ask a different question. If you ask a new question spend more time explaining the background than you did here. Don't supply details by leaking them out in comments to answers. Try to get the detail in the question.